# sql query PDO bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was trying to insert email and email password to a table where it already contains the username and password. the query i am using :

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include 'config.php';   
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $uname = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['passne'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(email, emailpassword) VALUES (:uname, :pass) WHERE username = :username";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':uname', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    echo "Success";
?>
```

but it shows this error

**Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = 'thansiya123'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\update.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\b\update.php(14): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\update.php on line 14**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `INSERT INTO users(email, emailpassword) VALUES (:uname, :pass) WHERE username = :username`

This is not valid SQL. If a record already exists for the given user and you want to set some fields, you want an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE users set email = :uname, emailpassword = :pass where username = :username
```